# C# main app move to main screen not where it was launched from

Tags: c#, monitor

If I have more than two monitors, my C# / .NET app opens on a monitor different from the one it was on when I ran the executable. This is fine but all the child windows pop up on the screen it was ran from not the main window. I need it one way or the other, not both.

Example.

- Monitor:1 open app.
- Splash screen opens on monitor 1
- Main app loads on monitor 2 (main)
- Login prompt on window 1.

I have tried using the screen class but my screen does not move.

```
Login login = new Login();
login.ShowInTaskbar = false;
login.Owner = this;
this.Location = Screen.GetWorkingArea(login).Location;//this is my main application that moves off the screen. I'm trying to bring it back.
login.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Why not use [StartPosition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.startposition?view=net-5.0) and set to [CenterParent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.formstartposition?view=net-5.0)?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I guess my main app was set to manual where all other were set to default windows position.  This fixed it.